# C# 7.1 and 7.2 Span and ReadOnlySpan

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, c#-7.2, c#-7.1

I am using Visual Studio 15.5.6 version.

When I create a simple console application project I can't use `ReadOnlySpan` or `Span` or `Memory`.
I set the project to .Net Framework 4.7.1, because in Visual Studio that is the latest version.

Is there anybody using `ReadOnlySpan<T>` or `Span<T>`?

My purpose is to increase the code work speed.

```
ReadOnlySpan<char> charSpans="Test Words".AsReadOnlySpan();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the prereleased Nuget package system.memory to use Span.  Note this is for .net Core 2.0, .net standard 1.0 or 2.0, PCL, UAP 10.1 and Xamarin.Mac.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/4.4.0-preview1-25305-02

Read this article for more info on Span

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx

Comment: Hi @Ken Tucker i download on package manager console and it is support for .net 4.7.1 Thank you for download link. I marked this answer the correct. You should remove .net 4.7.1 text.

Comment: @MuratCanOĞUZHAN System.Memory doesn't allow you to use AsReadOnlySpan on 4.7.1 that I can find